# Android - error opening trace file: No such file or directory(2)

Tags: android

I am developing an android application and one part of it is to check whether the wifi of the phone is enabled or not.

I am running the application directly on mobile phone.These are some errors

```
error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
Refusing to reopen boot DEX 'system/framework/hwframework.jar'
```

This is my manifest file

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.demo"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.demo.Test_allActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I am very new to android , and can't figure out the solution. Thanks is advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you need the [ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE) in your manifest.

Answer (score -2):

Need to check your main class(MainActivity) file is mentioned or not in 'Manifest.xml'.

```
<activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name="com.androidexample.demo.MainActivity" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
</activity>
```