# Android application doesn't start for uncaught exception

Tags: android, exception, android-manifest, startup, uncaught-exception

My application doesn't start anymore. It stops even before starting the first activity. Logcat shows the well know lines:

```
11-22 19:43:19.040: E/Trace(22750): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
11-22 19:43:19.080: W/dalvikvm(22750): Refusing to reopen boot DEX '/system/framework/hwframework.jar'
11-22 19:43:19.230: W/dalvikvm(22750): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41ae7438)
```

The onCreate method of the first activity is this:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splashscreen);
        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
            @Override
            public void uncaughtException(Thread paramThread, Throwable paramThrowable) {
                Log.w("Alert","Lets See if it Works !!!", paramThrowable);
            }
        });
    }
```

Neither moving the handler, nor adding a Log.i as first action the application responds. The manifest file has minSdkVersion=8 and targe = 17, but it has never been modified and it previously worked. I read several threads related both to the first two lines, and the last one in particular, but none of them seems to fit with my needs of seeing the application. Is there any way to debug this error? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need to add the [ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE) permission to your manifest file

These posts might help:

> [android Map Application Trace Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17669292/android-map-application-trace-error)
>
> [App can't be opened with the error in opening trace file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19225602/app-cant-be-opened-with-the-error-in-opening-trace-file)
>
> [Android - error opening trace file: No such file or directory(2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16132807/android-error-opening-trace-file-no-such-file-or-directory2)

Comment: unluckily it's already in my manifest, it has always been there.